# Django Rest Framework won't let me have more than one permission

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with the Django Rest Framework and permissions. DRF won't let me have more than one permission on my views for example.

If I login to the API as an admin user I can get access using this mixin:

```
class PermissionMixin(object):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser)
```

Now, if I add a second permission mixin:

```
class PermissionMixin(object):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser, TokenHasReadWriteScope)
```

Admin users are denied access. What should happen is both admin user and users with a token get access, however with above now only TokenHasReadWriteScope users have access.

Has anyone else had this issue, whats going on here?

I need both type of users to have access.

This is how my view looks:

```
class SomeList(PermissionMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView)

    queryset = Award.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AwardSerializer
```

PS TokenHasReadWriteScope is from [django-oauth-toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.4.1/rest-framework/permissions.html)

Comment: I suppose you did "from oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework import TokenHasReadWriteScope" ?! What does the error in the console look like?

Comment: @wagner-felix Hi, thanks for the response. Yes I have imported correctly. There are no errors at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is absolutely normal, that's how DRF was designed. If you want to have at least one of those permission classes, you need to specify a more 'complex' condition. [This](https://github.com/caxap/rest_condition) is a very good example of what you might use. After you install it, you can use it like this:

```
from rest_condition import Or
...
permission_classes = (Or(permissions.IsAdminUser, TokenHasReadWriteScope),)
```

Comment: I had no idea this was the case. Thank you. Where is this documented?

Comment: rest_condition does not exist. where is this imported from?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where it is documented. I know from personal experience that DRF applies ALL permission classes in a certain order. And the link that I gave you is something I found when I had a problem just like yours. Another possible solution would be to write your own permission class, in which you check that at least one of those two permissions is true.

Comment: I see. I've give it a shot. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's incredible this isn't built in... I feel like there is less of a use case for AND'ing permissions then OR'ing them. Either way, you can get it from here: https://github.com/caxap/rest_condition

Answer (score 26):

With [version 3.9 and above of Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/#composable-permission-classes), they have built-in support for composable permission classes and you can use and/or-operators out of the box:

```
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated & (ReadOnly | IsAdmin)]
```