# django rest permissions allow both IsAdmin and custom permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have a views.py as below,

```
from webapi.permissions import IsOwner

class MemberDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = members.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,IsOwner)
```

And the following is custom permission to check if the user is ower of object in webapi.permissions,

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
            return obj.owner == request.user
```

Now the issue is it is check if he is a admin user and gives permissions to update / delete, But if the owner is the user it should actually give permission to edit he data but in this case it is failing.

On seeing the question "[Django Rest Framework won't let me have more than one permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884245/django-rest-framework-wont-let-me-have-more-than-one-permission)" I tried as below also still it did not work when I use Or,

```
class MemberDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = members.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    permission_classes = (Or(permissions.IsAdminUser,IsOwner))
```

If I use Or it is failing with error during run time as "'Condition' object is not iterable"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get OR permissions instead of AND in REST framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557156/how-to-get-or-permissions-instead-of-and-in-rest-framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need give edit permissions for admin and owner users only, you can implement custom permission class:

```
class IsOwnerOrAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.owner == request.user or request.user.is_admin
```

And use only this one in the view:

```
permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdmin]
```

This method is documented [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples).

Comment: This works in a better way, I have removed Or and using the custom permissions.

Comment: If someone just copies this code, be aware that written as-is it also gives read-only access for anyone, not just owner or admin (the SAFE_METHODS check).

Answer (score 5):

Since DRF [3.9](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/#composable-permission-classes), you can use the logical bitwise operators `|` and `&` (`~` was added in [3.9.2](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#392)).

As outlined in [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) you would just need

```py
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser|IsOwner,)
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using tuple syntax but you need comma to act as a tuple
replace
`permission_classes = (Or(permissions.IsAdminUser,IsOwner))`
with
`permission_classes = (Or(permissions.IsAdminUser,IsOwner), )`

Comment: Yes this doesn't give any error, but now still anyone is able to edit it means Permissions.IsAdminUser and IsOwser is not into effect

Comment: which `Or` do you use, there isn't built-in conditions in rest framework

Comment: I installed using pip and using the module "from rest_condition import Or
" , module "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rest_condition"

Comment: what's the problem now, any one can edit or no one can edit
which class is in action now ?